# Сколько цифр в числе

Tags: java

Имеется натуральное число `n`. Как получить число цифр в этом числе?

```
int n = 33;
int numberDigits = ???
```

Comment: Задано натуральное число, зачем дабл?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не надо никаких циклов, можно использовать логарифм

```
Math.ceil(Math.log10(x))
```

Для страховки можно использовать Math.ceil(Math.log10(x + 0.5))

Собственно, проверил и получил такие вот результаты (3 варианта вычисления: логарифм, деление, сдвиг):

1. Логарифм работает за константное время и, согласен, не так уж быстро, как хотелось бы
2. Сдвиг и деление работают линейно от длины числа, причем сдвиг примерно в пять раз быстрее деления.
3. На десятизначных числах на long(это как раз порядка Integer.MAX_VALUE) логарифм так же быстр, как и сдвиг.

Вот, теперь можно почти точно сказать, что логарифм следует использовать только для long, и то, лишь с уверенностью, что будут меряться действительно *длинные* числа, больше десяти знаков.

Вот тестилка, можно и самим проверить, кто желает. На вход подается количество итераций.

```
import sun.misc.Perf;

public class IntegerMeter{
    static Perf perf = Perf.getPerf();
    static long frequency = perf.highResFrequency();

    static int countDigits_A(long number){
        int result = 0;
        for(long match = 0L; number > match; ++result)
            match = (match << 3) + (match << 1) + 9L;
        return result;
    }
    static int countDigits_B(long number){
        return (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(number + 0.5));
    }
    static int countDigits_C(long number){
        int result = 0;
        while(number != 0L){
            ++result;
            number /= 10;
        }
        return result;
    }
    static int countDigits_A(int number){
        int result = 0;
        for(int match = 0; number > match; ++result)
            match = (match << 3) + (match << 1) + 9;
        return result;
    }
    static int countDigits_B(int number){
        return (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(number + 0.5));
    }
    static int countDigits_C(int number){
        int result = 0;
        while(number != 0){
            ++result;
            number /= 10;
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static double test(Runnable runnable, int count){
        long begin = perf.highResCounter();
        while(count-- > 0) runnable.run();
        long end = perf.highResCounter();
        return (double)(end - begin) / frequency;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final long candidateLong = 5464456734L;
        final int candidateInt = (int) candidateLong;
        int count = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double testLong_A = test(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){ countDigits_A(candidateLong); }
        }, count);
        double testLong_B = test(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){ countDigits_B(candidateLong); }
        }, count);
        double testLong_C = test(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){ countDigits_C(candidateLong); }
        }, count);
        double testInt_A = test(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){ countDigits_A(candidateInt); }
        }, count);
        double testInt_B = test(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){ countDigits_B(candidateInt); }
        }, count);
        double testInt_C = test(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){ countDigits_C(candidateInt); }
        }, count);
        System.out.printf("%.5f\t%.5f\t%.5f\r\n%.5f\t%.5f\t%.5f\r\n",
                testLong_A, testLong_B, testLong_C, testInt_A, testInt_B, testInt_C);
    }
}
```

Comment: Думаете это эффективнее чем деление в цикле ?

Comment: Думаю - да, хотя этот вопрос требует проверки

Comment: Вы считаете, что вычисление логарифма реализовано native кодом ? В таком случае возможно и быстрее. Проверьте на досуге.

Comment: Логарифм вычисляется native кодом - это определенно. Другое дело, что там используются тяжеловесные инструкции для сопроцессора - вот это серьезно влияет на скорость.

Answer (score 8):

Способ первый, медленный и для извращенцев, но достаточно топорный: перевести число в строку и узнать её в длину.
Способ второй, побыстрее: циклом, пока число больше нуля, делить его на 10 (каждый раз уменьшать количество цифр на одну) и увеличивать счётчик.

Comment: я бы лучше сделал вторым способом, он более такой программисткий. Первый способ тоже нооорм, но по сути это хак. :)

Comment: Для целого это не хак (через строку), это просто некрасиво (во всех смыслах). В общем случае делить надо на основание системы счисления.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда так проверял:

```
$a = 12345;

$b = strlen($a);

print"b - $b";
```

Comment: Java тут причем ? Вопрос был о программе на языке java.

Comment: Фактически вы написали первую часть первого ответа на php.

Answer (score 0):

Так будет не проще?....

System.out.println(Integer.bitCount(n));

Comment: Вы спрашивате или отвечаете?

Comment: Какая разница проще или нет, если результат неверен.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 7654328;
int r = (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(x)+1);
```

С числами больше 0!

Answer (score -3):

```
String str="";
str=Double.toString(a);
System.out.println(str.lenght());
```

Comment: хм... напомнило `boolean b = false; ... if (b.toString().length == 4){/**/}`

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.